# How to update table sqlite with python in loop

Tags: python, sqlite

I am trying to calculate the mode value of each row and store the value in the judge = judge column, however it updates only the first record and leaves the loop

ps: Analisador is my table and resultado_2 is my db

```py
import sqlite3
import statistics

conn = sqlite3.connect("resultado_2.db")
cursor = conn.cursor()

data = cursor.execute("SELECT Bow, FastText, Glove, Wordvec, Python, juiz, id FROM Analisador")

for x in data:
    list = [x[0],x[1],x[2],x[3],x[4],x[5],x[6]]
    mode = statistics.mode(list)
    try: 
        cursor.execute(f"UPDATE Analisador SET juiz={mode} where id={row[6]}") #row[6] == id
        conn.commit()
    except:
        print("Error")
conn.close()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to fetch your records after SQL is executed:

```
cursor.execute("SELECT Bow, FastText, Glove, Wordvec, Python, juiz, id FROM Analisador")
data = cursor.fetchall()
```

That type of SQL query is different from UPDATE (that you're using in your code too) which doesn't need additional step after SQL is executed.

Comment: This works for me, thanks bro, what is the command fetchall()?

Comment: You've created a helper cursor object that is responsible for retrieving objects. When you execute `fetchall` it returns all the records the cursor gets, for example with `fetchone` you'll get a single/first record.